# Internal server error when no file specified or file is missing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I am using this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ data/photos/$1 [L]
```

Its doing that, when I use f.e `http://img.domain.com/profile_image.jpg` it will show content of file `http://www.domain.com/data/photos/profile_image.jpg` without changing url (masked). This is ok.

The problem is, just in case, when somebody enter `http://img.domain.com`, it will return 500 Internal server error, but I want it to show 403 Forbidden, the same as when you enter `http://www.domain.com/data/photos/`. I am helpless, how to modify this rewrite rule to achieve this?

**EDITED:**

Also the same issue is when the file doesnt exist in `/data/photos/`, then I want to return 404... but its returning 500.

In errorlog is too many recursions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check whether destination file exists and then rewrite it:

```
# 403 for img subdomain when request is for landing page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(data/photos)?/?$ - [F,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/data/photos/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ data/photos/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is working for missing file. And how can I handle `img.domain.com` to show 403?

Comment: `img.domain.com/file.jpg` => `www.domain.com/data/photos/file.jpg` (return 200, working), `img.domain.com/unexistingfile.jpg` => `www.domain.com/data/photos/unexistingfile.jpg` (return 404, working), `img.domain.com` => `www.domain.com/data/photos/` (neverending recursion; should return 403)

Comment: Yes, now everything is working. Thanks a lot. Just one more small question, does it really need to escape `.` with `\.`? Because its working also without.

Comment: Yes it will work without escaping but in theory it can also match `img-domain.com` since dot matches any char (though that request will never arrive to your Apache)